# Quick advice on "casting" variables? Very short function needing adjustment

Tags: c++, types, casting, type-conversion

I have some C++ code that is in this format:

```
    void calculate(int a, float b, long c) {

    long long result = (a / b) * (1000 / c);
    assert(result > 0);

    // more code...
    }
```

However, the assert statement fails. It is a given that a, b, and c are all values that are positive. Then I take it that 'result' ends up becoming 'result == 0' for some reason. Is there something inherent in the logic of the type conversions presented here that is causing my code to fail?

I am new to C++ so the answer may seem obvious...

Comment: What are the values of a, b, and c when it fails the assertion ?

Comment: It's most likely a value, v, 0 < v < 1 and then it is being forced into an integer type (long long) so it's being floored (essentially) down to 0.  To know for sure though, as GWW said, we'll need to know what you're passing in.

Comment: The way this is configured to run, I have to run 'make', and then 'make graph0.pdf'

So apparently including a printf() in the code doesn't print anything....!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `c > 1000`, then the expression `(1000/c)` becomes zero due to integer division. Integer division is being performed here because both operands are integral types.

As a result, the expression `(a / b) * (1000 / c)` becomes zero, so the value of `result` becomes zero, triggering the assert.

The same thing will happen if `b > a`, for the same reason as above.

If integer division is not what you want, rewrite your expression like this:

```
long long result = long long((float(a) / b) * (1000.0f / c));
```

This invokes floating-point division instead of integer division. The value of `a` and `c` will be converted to a floating-point type for the purposes of calculating the result.

Comment: Hey In silico, apparently that is not working... what about 'a' and 'b'? Even though b is a float, could it fail since a is still an int?

Comment: It might be desirable to use `1000.` instead of `1000.f` to take advantage of the better precision of doubles.

Comment: @DarkTemplar What are the values of `a`, `b`, and `c` at the entry to the function? If `(a / b) * (1000.0f / c)` is less than 1, it will be truncated to zero in the initialisation of `result`.

Comment: Even after your latest edit, and also after Mankarse's advice, it still fails :(

Comment: @Dark Templar: What are your inputs, and what output are you expecting?

Comment: Hmm, well I am actually not given the exact values of the inputs, but I am basically guaranteed that they work for this particular task. So it could just be the logic that I've come up with in this function...

So you guys are saying that as long as the calculation is NOT less than 1, the result should definitely work?

Comment: @Dark Templar: I can't guarantee that because I don't know exactly what the actual task is. The problem is that there will be truncation because integers can't represent every single possible number representable by a floating point. Surely you have a specification that tells you exactly what output should result from the inputs.

Comment: You don't need the cast on `float(a)`, it'll automatically be converted to a float (or double, can't remember) because b is a float.